# Saving nameless textboxes into Database in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, textbox

I'm a student currently doing my programming coursework. I have created a piece of code which creates text boxes for the user to input the names of tracks from a vinyl. As you can choose the amount of text boxes you create, these text boxes end up not having a name (e.g. textbox1, textbox2...), this makes me unsure of how to send the values of the textboxes to the database table. The table is currently empty and only has one column. Could someone please let me know how I will send these values to the database and also the code to create a new column for the tracks. Here is my current code below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Label11.Show()
    GroupBox1.Show()

    GroupBox1.AutoSize = True

    Dim number As Integer
    number = TextBox8.Text
    Dim boxes(number) As TextBox
    Dim newbox As TextBox

    For i As Integer = 1 To number
        newbox = New TextBox
        newbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(100, 20)
        newbox.Location = New Point(10, 10 + 25 * (i - 1))
        AddHandler newbox.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox_TextChanged
        boxes(i) = newbox
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(newbox)
        newbox.Name = ("Trackbox" & i)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: they are only nameless because you didnt give them a `.Name`.  your `boxes` array is meaningless because it only exists in that event, but with form/class level `Scope` it (or better, a List(Of T)) could be used to get the textbox text when needed. e.g. `boxes(n).Text` or `Controls(ListofBoxNames(n)).Text`

Comment: I only need it to exist in that event, the form which this code is in is to add a new vinyl to the database. It turns out my program names the boxes "Trackbox" and then the number of created boxes. How do i make my code create new columns in my database?

Comment: but you dont **use** `boxes()` anywhere in that event, so it is meaningless.  are you sure you want to add a **column** for each control instead of a row?  (and I see the name prop now).  Isnt there already a table with columns for the data?

Comment: As @Plutonix suggests, if you were to remove the lines "Dim boxes(number) As TextBox" and "boxes(i) = newbox", it would make absolutely no difference to your code. Do you really want this code in a button click procedure where the user can click multiple times and recreate textboxes? If so, it will need some more work to get that to work. If not then put the code in your form load event procedure. I have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your boxes array needs to be declared at form level.

```
Private boxes() As TextBox

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Label11.Show()
    GroupBox1.Show()

    GroupBox1.AutoSize = True

    Dim number As Integer
    'need to insert validation code here to make sure a number is entered in TextBox8
    number = Integer.Parse(TextBox8.Text)
    ReDim boxes(number) 
    Dim newbox As TextBox

    For i As Integer = 1 To number
        newbox = New TextBox
        newbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(100, 20)
        newbox.Location = New Point(10, 10 + 25 * (i - 1))
        AddHandler newbox.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox_TextChanged
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(newbox)
        newbox.Name = ("Trackbox" & i.ToString)
        boxes(i) = newbox
    Next

End Sub
```

Then you can reference your text boxes as follows:

```
MessageBox.Show(boxes(5).Text)
```